# Sed: get lines beginning with some prefix

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I have file Blackberry jad file:

```
RIM-COD-URL-12: HelloWorld-12.cod
RIM-COD-Size: 68020
RIM-MIDlet-Icon-2-1: ____HOVER_ICON_res/icon/blackberry/icon-68.png,focused
RIM-COD-URL-11: HelloWorld-11.cod
RIM-MIDlet-Icon-Count-2: 1
RIM-COD-URL-10: HelloWorld-10.cod
RIM-MIDlet-Icon-Count-1: 1
MIDlet-Vendor: Vasia Pupkin
RIM-MIDlet-Icon-1-1: res\icon\blackberry\____HOVER_ICON_icon-68.png,focused
Manifest-Version: 1.0
RIM-MIDlet-Flags-1: 0
RIM-COD-SHA1-38: 9a c8 b3 35 72 de 34 5e 7a 0a 5b 9e c3 3a 65 4c 20 0f 8e 50
```

I just want to get lines begin with `RIM-COD-`.

Can you provide me solutions for `awk` or `sed`?

Comment: `grep -v ^RIM-COD-` should do it without any fuss.

Comment: Sorry, I read your question backwards - there's a double negative in there that got me.  What I gave you will remove the lines that *do* start with `RIM-COD-`.  To keep those lines, you want `grep ^RIM-COD-`.

Comment: @CarlNorum I just did the same as yours, +2 to your comments. first grep -V came up, then found the word trick.....

Comment: @Kent Сan you please update my question to make it more understandable

Comment: @CAMOBAP updated base on the accepted answer.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Use `sed -n` and only print lines that match RIM-COD.

```
sed -n -e '/^RIM-COD-/p' yourfile.txt
```

Answer (score 36):

Try doing this :

```
awk '/^RIM-COD/' file.txt
```

Or

```
grep "^RIM-COD" file.txt
```

Or

```
sed -n '/^RIM-COD/p' file.txt
```